# Attach an image to a contact

Tags: android, image, contacts

I am having exactly the same problem as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4175).

I am trying to use this Intent:
`android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE`

`Starts an Activity that lets the user pick a contact to attach an image to.`
Sounds suitable to me but unfortunately results in an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Code:

```
import android.provider.ContactsContract;  
...  
try {  
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();  
    myIntent.setAction(ContactsContract.Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE);  
    myIntent.setData(imageUri);  
    startActivity(myIntent);  
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {  
    Log.e("ImageContact", 
            "Firing Intent to set image as contact failed.", anfe);  
    showToast(this, "Firing Intent to set image as contact failed.");  
}
```

I cannot find any error in the code above. The `imageUri` is correct for following code is working perfectly:

Code:

```
try {  
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();  
    myIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
    myIntent.setData(imageUri);  
    startActivity(myIntent);  
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {  
    Log.e("ImageContact", 
            "Firing Intent to set image as contact failed.", anfe);  
    showToast(this, "Firing Intent to set image as contact failed.");  
}
```

As mentioned in the link this results in a another menu before getting to the contacts. That is acceptable but not perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you already know the file path you can use:

```
values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName);
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, currentTime);
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(Images.Media.ORIENTATION, 0);
values.put(Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
values.put(Images.Media.SIZE, size);

getContentResolver().insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

This way no nead to open a bitmap stream if you already have the file.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a little more success using by setting the Uri using the following code taken from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

However, after selecting a contact and cropping the image the new contact icon still is not set?

```
// Save the name and description of an image in a ContentValues map.  
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(3);
values.put(Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "road_trip_1");
values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, "Day 1, trip to Los Angeles");
values.put(Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");

// Add a new record without the bitmap, but with the values just set.
// insert() returns the URI of the new record.
Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

// Now get a handle to the file for that record, and save the data into it.
// Here, sourceBitmap is a Bitmap object representing the file to save to the database.
try {
    OutputStream outStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
    sourceBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, outStream);
    outStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "exception while writing image", e);
}
```

Comment: It seems to work fine with 1.6, 2.1, 2.2 - 2.0.1 seems to have a bug were the contact image can't be set manually from a gallery image anyway.

Comment: Thx for your response. Are you going for a workaround reading the contacts IDs and attaching an image directly or are aou still using the intent "android.provider.ContactsContract.Intents.ATTACH_IMAGE"? Reading the content-provider page it seems to me, I would have to build my own contact list to get the IDs, then let the user select one and then overwrite his/ her image. Or did I missunderstand something?

Comment: I'm using Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA) gives me the two intent activities for setting a contact icon and wallpaper that I was after. Sorry can't help you with the contacts IDs problem.

Comment: One warning on the above code - after adding the contact you have to manually delete the image created in the camera folder. I've not as yet found a nicer way to create the Uri in a temp manner. startActivityForResult isn't any help as contacts.AttachImage returns the cancel flag :(

Comment: hm, sorry, I probably wasn't clear in the beginning. I have an image in my gallery taken by an camera intent and therefore already in the mediastore. I have an URI to that image and I want to attach that specific image to a contact (that the user chooses). I fail to see how the code above can help me with that :(