# Android save contact image programmatically

Tags: android

I am working on one application in which i need to store the contact pro-grammatically. I have successfully saved the contact but not able to save the contact image.

I didn't found any example for the same.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried already? What format is the image in? Do you have any code to post?

Comment: Did you actually search this site before posting this question?  Duplicate of question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4879134/346309

Answer (score 4):

To save the photo during the initial insert

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops =
          new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
...
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

// intial setup
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
         .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType)
         .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
         .build());

// add name with rawId backreference
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
          .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
          .withValue(StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, "John Smith")
          .build());

// add the photo
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
          .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
          .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo. CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
          .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, bitmapByteArray
          .build());

getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
```

Where bitmapByteArray is the byte array of the bitmap you want to attach to the contact

One way to get the byte array from a bitmap image

```
public byte[] toByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, stream);
        return stream.toByteArray();
}
```